# Where can I find reference documentation and tutorials for new JavaScript based macros?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-macros

Microsoft has decided to bring back Macros in VS 2013+. Great and a big thank you. But they use now JavaScript instead of VB so being the 1% of developers that has been using them ever since, I have to rewrite my treasures into JavaScript now. I spent hours searching the internet but could not find anything that would explain the new macros in detail.

To some extent I could help myself by first recording what I wanted to do and then copy that sequence of macro commands from the recorded into my custom macro. That works for simple linear code but when I want to do more complex things, e.g. calls of subprograms and functions, loops, variable declarations, their scope, etc. I am lost, I couldn't find anything on that.

So could someone point me to a comprehensive top-down documentation and/or tutorial of the new Visual Studio Macros?

Comment: Sorry, but such kind of questions are off-topic on stackoverflow. And in case you don't get any helpful answers/comments; maybe you could try quora.com

Comment: Great, thank you GhostCat indeed, this was very helpful end encouraging! The developer community definitely needs more people like you. Btw. what exactly is wrong with my question? Should I have posted every single statement to get help?

Comment: You are welcome. And the close request should tell you what I think the problem is: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: It could be due to the fact that English is not my mother tongue that you obviously do not understand my question. I did not askt for a _recommendation_ of something, I asked where something existing is _documented_. While a recomendation is the opinion of the person who is recommending something, a hint is dealing with facts. I hope you get the small but important difference. So as I said, thank you for help, you have been very bright, indeed...

Comment: Obviously your question doesn't draw much attention; or any other visible feedback. My suggestion: Microsoft has a huge developer community; did you try some of the MSDN forums?

Comment: Yes GhostCat, I did this already even before this post. With exactly the same result. So my conclusion is that this new Macro feature seems to be just another marketing gag of Microsoft. And all the investment into development of those macros is obviously lost. Hope you can feel the frustration...

Comment: The only thing left then: quora.com ... sometimes you find surprisingly specific answers there.